# Is JSR-354 Money API ready for production usage?

Tags: api, java-8, currency, bigdecimal, java-money

Nowadays, i'm doing research about which data type would be proper for money/currency in Java 8.

I've encountered JSR-354 specification for data types and operations on money/currency
data. Reference implementation with its API is here: https://github.com/JavaMoney

I've tried to learn the api on version *0.9* through examples on the web. It was cool and easy. But
when i updated the version of api to *1.0*, then i realized that core builder classes 
such `MonetaryCurrencies`, `MonetaryAmounts` and `MonetaryFunctions` class that contains monetary functions have been removed completely instead of being marked as **Deprecated**.

Is it normal to do such huge changes on the API? Has anyone tried JavaMoney Api in production?

What's your recommendations other than `BigDecimal` and `java.util.Currency` for representing money/currency data?

Comment: @mabi Programmers is now Software Engineering, to better represent the scope of the site. Questions such as this would be considered off-topic (recommending libraries) or primarily opinion based (what is considered production-ready by one team or organization may not be considered production ready by someone else). I can see that you have an account, but no participation on Software Engineering. You should avoid recommending sites that you don't understand - when a question that isn't a good fit is posted and it ends up being down voted, closed, and deleted, that's a poor user experience.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I see, sorry about this. Then, where *would* a question like "what's the reason behind these API changes?" go?

Comment: @mabi The development team behind the API, ideally after searching any mailing lists, forums, or documentation produced by the development team. They are the only people who can provide an authoritative answer to that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tried JSR-354 in production. I've used Money concepts getting inspiration from https://github.com/stephenh/timeandmoney.

This is a mirror of the code from the [Time and Money library](http://timeandmoney.sourceforge.net) from Eric Evans - author of Domain Driven Design

Comment: Currency here is Turkish Lira(TL). This library has no support for the TL. I know that can be added on TL support but i'm looking for a library that can be used directly without modifying. Thanks for your recommendation. I bookmark it for future projects.

Comment: I'm not actually using the library as is, I write my own code using this library as a guide.